# Can JS have getters and setters methods named same as property?

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

I want to achieve behaviour like down in code:

```
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

var myFoo = new Foo('myName');

myFoo.name('newMyName'); // sets myFoo.name = 'newMyName'
myFoo.name(); // returns 'myName'
```

But it is obvious that in that case I'm overridding name property with name function. Is anyhow possible to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Why don't you use another name to store the actual string (ex. `.name2`), and have `.name` be a function, and then just define the other property within the function?

Comment: I think you can [use getter and setter with the same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters). Although that [requires IE>=9](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Getter_in_property_initializer).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When talking about getters and setters in javascript you may be talking about one of two concepts:

### 1. Getters and setters as a concept like in any other OO language.

This is the case illustrated by the code in your question. In this case, an object's property is simply that, a property which may be either an object or a function. Javascript keeps track of both within the same namespace. Indeed, functions are just objects in javascript so there is no concept of a separate namespace for functions like you'd find in languages like C.

In this case "getters" and "setters" are just regular functions so the value needs to be stored separately. There are several strategies around this.

One is to use implicit `getSomething()` and `setSomething()` style functions commonly found in Java. This allows you to disambiguate the getters and setters from the property name since the getters and setters have the word "get" and "set" added to the name.

The second strategy is the one you've written in your question. In this case you need to store the property in another name so as not to share the same name with the getter/setter.

The third strategy is to store the value in a closure:

```
    function Foo (name) {
        var name = name;
        this.name = function (str) {
            if (str !== undefined) name = str;
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Note that in the code above the value is stored in `name` but the getter/setter is `this.name` which is a completely different variable. This allows your example code to work as you expected:

```
    var me = new Foo('Mark');
    me.name(); // returns Mark
    me.name('Andy'); // sets name to Andy
```

### 2. Getters and setters as a mechanism in javascript.

This is a feature of newer versions of javascript that follows the ECMAscript 5 specification. This feature allows properties to execute code when reading or writing to it similar to how the `.innerHTML` property of DOM object invokes the HTML parser when you assign something to it.

The syntax of getters and setters is similar to functions but introduces the `get` and `set` keywords in place of `function`.

A simple example of a property with getter and setter:

```
    var me = {
        first_name : "",
        last_name : "",
        get name() {
            return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
        },
        set name(str) {
            var n = str.split(/\s+/);
            this.first_name = n.shift();
            this.last_name = n.join(' ');
        }
    }
```

The code above allows you to treat the functions to get and set the `first_name` and `last_name` as if it is a variable instead of a function. To use the `name` getter and setter you'd simply do:

```
    me.name = "James Bond";
    alert(me.first_name); // should alert James
    alert(me.last_name); // should alert Bond
    me.last_name = "Dean";
    alert(me.name); // should alert James Dean
```

**Using the javascript get/set mechanism, you can't store the value in the object using the same name.** For example:

```
    var foo = {
        set bar(x) {this.bar=x}
    }
```

The code above will compile but trying to set bar: `foo.bar = 1` will cause a stack overflow because of the infinite loop - the `this.bar=` inside the setter will call the setter again.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for. Problem was that both property and method(get/set) shared same scope.

Comment: @slebetman I love this answer. Two questions: 1. So there is no other benefit between the two concepts (if you use the second strategy for the first concept) than using () or not using () to trigger the getter/setter? 2. Is there a way to automatically run the set mechanism of an object if you create a new instance of an object?

Comment: I'm wondering how eg. Document object in JS works, that there are lots of getter/setter properties like, children, title, etc. when I browse it in Chrome console I can see that getter/setter has got the same name.

Comment: @Paweł DOM objects are generally implemented in C, not js. The getter/setter-like behavior already existed before the getter/setter API was implemented. Indeed, the getter/setter API was created to allow you to emulate the behavior of DOM properties like innerHTML which was impossible before

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JavaScript getter/setter with the same name as the properties, e.g. to intercept certain setters to implement side effects, you can create a `Proxy` for your object.

```
function editableProxy (myObj) {
    return new Proxy(myObj, {
        toJSON: () => myObj,
        get: function (target, prop) {
            return Reflect.get(myObj, prop);
        },
        set: function (target, prop, receiver) {
            if (prop === 'billTo') {
                myObj.billToId = receiver?.id;
            }
            return Reflect.set(myObj, prop, receiver);
        },
    });
};
```

All getters work normally. Setters work normally, but if you set a `billTo` it also sets a billToId.

```
let da = {id:123}
let wrapped = editableProxy(da)
let id = wrapped.id // 123
wrapped.id=234
wrapped.id===da.id // true
wrapped.billTo={id:567,name:'Big Bad Bill'} // triggers setter side effect
wrapped.billToId // 567
```