# Why is it that even after a stack overflow error, in getter and setter methods, the rest of my code still works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

I'm currently learning about setters and getters in Javascript but I ran into an issue. I've named a property in my class the same name as my get and set methods which I understand can lead to recursion and cause a stack overflow but why is it that 'msg' still gets assigned to 'Sandra' even after the stack overflow error?

```js
class ClassWithGetSet{
    msg = 'Hello'; 
    get msg(){
        return this.msg;
    }

    set msg(x){
        this.msg = `Hello ${x}`;
    }
}

const instance = new ClassWithGetSet(); 
console.log(instance.msg); 
instance.msg = 'Sandra'; 
console.log(instance.msg);
```

I expected an error to output on the Chrome DevTools console but instead it printed 'Hello' and then'Sandra'. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's just a single plain property called `msg` on the instance, you're not accessing the getter and setter.

Comment: I take it you're referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533561/283366) in regards to any stack overflow error. I'd say things have changed since 2013 when it was first written. I see no error when running your code and the setter is ignored

Comment: To clarify, do you actually get an error reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_getters_in_classes) :

> Getter properties are defined on the prototype property of the class and are thus shared by all instances of the class.

Thus, when looking up the property, it finds the instance's before the getter/setter pair. You're never reaching them.